# Is there any usage of $x^x$ in physics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematics

I am so excited about the function: $x^x$.

I would like to know if there is any usage in the physics world of this function. Is there any formula that uses $x^x$?

Comment: Lambert W function solves sometimes RG flow equations

Comment: @John the Lambert W function is the inverse of $x\mapsto xe^x$, instead of $x\mapsto x^x=e^{x\ln(x)}$, which is function at hand.

Comment: Physicists are not too excited about the function $x^x$ because they don't generally use powers with arbitrary bases. Instead, they use the exponential with the base $e=2.718...$. So your function may be rewritten as $\exp(x\ln x)$. Of course that similar functions appear at various places but because of its composite structure, it's much less omnipresent or fundamental than $\exp(x)$ and $\ln(x)$ separately.

Comment: @LubošMotl That still leaves open the question of whether $\exp(x\ln x)$ appears in any physical theory (not that I know of any or would expect it to).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ways of rearranging a system is related to the entropy by $W=e^S$.

The entropy is given by $S=\sum_i p_i \log p_i$ where $p_i$ is the probability of realising a given microstate.

Hence $W = \prod_i \, p_i^{\,p_i}$

Comment: AFAICS, "number of ways of rearranging a system" is only a correct description of $W$ in the microcanonical ensemble, where the $p_i$ are all equal and it doesn't _really_ read $p_i^{p_i}$ (in a way other than that you can always rewrite $1 \equiv 1^1$). But $e^S$ is a useful quantity even in other ensembles, so: nice answer.